# Cypress intermittently fails to verify base url is running

Tags: node.js, node-modules, e2e-testing, cypress

I have just started experimenting with Cypress testing framework. I have a simple test running in a Jenkins job that is kicked off by an upstream job that installs and starts the server. It also runs some unit tests by hitting an url on the newly started server, so the server has to be started for it to complete successfully and kick off the cypress tests job.

For some reason cypress fails intermittently because it's unable to verify the server at the base url is running. I'm removed the base url config and am using the full url in `cy.visit()` and so far it has been running successfully.

Does anyone have an idea why Cypress is failing intermittently to verify the base url?

Here is the code that I'm using to run the tests. I'm running from a Gulp task:

```
gulp.task('run-ui-tests', function() {

return cypress.run({
      spec: './cypress/integration/main_navigation.js',
      config: {
          //baseUrl: config.urlProtocol + "://" + config.e2eTestsBaseUrl,
          viewportWidth: 1200,
          viewportHeight: 660,
          videoRecording: false,
          toConsole: false
      },
      reporter: "junit",
      reporterOptions: {
            mochaFile: "cypress/results/test-output.xml",
            toConsole: false,
            rootSuiteTitle: "UI Test Suite",
            testsuitesTitle: "UI Tests"
        }
    })
    .then((results) => {
        if (results.failures === 0) {
            console.log(results.passes + " of " + results.tests + " tests passed!")
            console.log(results.failures + " tests failed!")
            console.log("Ran for " + results.duration);
        } else {
            throw new Error(results.failures + " UI tests failed!! See /cypress/results/test-output.xml for more details.");
        }
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        throw new Error(err)
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out there was no DNS entry for the development server I was trying to run the test on. I got that entered and it's been working flawlessly ever since.